# Ruby Server responds with index, 404s everything else

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, geminabox

I've got a chef server I need to also use as a Ruby gem server. When I run `gem server` it says `Server started at 0.0.0.0:8808`. I can go to the hostname:8808 in a browser and see the gem server index page, listing all of the gems I expect to see, but all of the other directories ([link](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Server.html)) give 404s. I've tried this having run gem generate_index and with the --legacy option.

The box is configured to use Chef Server's embedded gem executable.

```
# which gem
/opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/gem
# gem env
...
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/chef-server/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
...
```

Listing what's in /opt/chef-server/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 shows directories for the pages listed in the gem server spec (e.g. gems,  quick, specifications).

I'm not really sure what the issue here is.

edit: I tried to use geminabox, instead of gem server.  I'm seeing the same issue as in [this](https://github.com/geminabox/geminabox/issues/121) github bug, which is not resolved.

Comment: Insufficient info. Would you please **copy+paste** some of those links that generate 404? And a path to them in the file system.

Comment: What I meant was "path to relevant files in the file system".

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Gem directory as a parameter to the server:

```
gem server --dir /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
```

The `gem env` for the current user may not be what you expect, which is why you're encountering this error.